# Symfony 4.3 dynamic database connection

Tags: symfony, database-connection

I have one database master and multiple client databases and I want to dynamically connect to client database what i can do?

```
$pem = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('db_private');

$params = $pem->getConnection()->getParams();
$params['dbname'] = 'db_user_1';


$configuration = $pem->getConfiguration();
$event_manager = $pem->getEventManager();

$cem = EntityManager::create($params, $configuration, $event_manager);

dd($cem->getRepository(dw_room::class)->findAll());
```

But I don't get data from the new database.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: i ask for dinamic conection and in docs is also described static conection

Comment: @VladyslavLevenets do you **really** have a dynamic db connection, or do you have a finite and know pool of possible db? If the answer is that you really have a dynamic db connection, I would kind of be afraid security wise, if that's the later case, the documentation pointed by Pierre still apply.

Comment: A clue is to create multiple entity manager as explained in documentation and a factory to return the good one that depend of your buisness logic

Comment: I have realy dinamic database conection because every user when register create a new database with same structure as other users databases but wich their credentials.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε i have 2 distinct database structures when first is master and second is used, when master is static and user is dynamic and connection to user database is established based on logged user.